# How do I integrate Oracle ODAC/ODP.NET into my Continuous Integration Process?

Tags: .net, oracle, continuous-integration, windows-server-2008, odac

I want to make sure I'm planning this right before I start making server changes. Please confirm if this path is a viable one.

### The Goal

- Utilize Oracle's ODP.NET to code against my currently existing enterprise database on Oracle 11g.

### The Puzzle Pieces

- **Dev Machine**: Win7 Enterprise 64-bit
- **Servers**:

  - Build Server (Windows 2008 R2 Standard)
  - Production Server (same)
- **Dev Environment**: VS 2012
- **Dev Stack**: ASP.NET MVC4, WebAPI, C#
- **Database**: Oracle 11g R(?)
- **CI Server**: CC.NET

### What I Think I'd like to Do:

1. Install ODP.NET onto my machine via ODAC (Universal Installer)
2. Install ODP.NET onto my build server (via xcopy)
3. Create ODBC connections on my machine and build server
4. Test ODBC connections
5. Test my code locally using Oracle's Provider to connect to the ODBC
   connection
6. Run CI Process like usual

### Question

Am I setting myself up for any pain by approaching it this way?

The documentation didn't necessarily mention how to set it up or where it fits in but it seems like this should be the way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.